# Answer wrongly deleted - 6 [resolved]

Tags: discussion, moderators, answers

In ever increasing list of wrongly deleted answers described [here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/641/please-stop-flagging-instantly-questions-answers-as-low-quality-if-they-are-on#comment2149_641), there is 1 more leaf got added:

[What is Hinduism's view on porn?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/15138/what-is-hinduisms-view-on-porn/15385#15385)

In this answer, I had posted images of [Khajuraho](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khajuraho_Group_of_Monuments#Arts_and_sculpture). As requested in question, obviously there cannot be "scriptures" on pornography as it's a modern term. So I found it appropriate to cite "sculptures"! Whether it's good/bad, is subjective & matter of up/down vote.

However the answer is deleted (I foresaw it happening), saying that some users found these images offensive.

> "People have complained about these images being offensive, so I'm deleting your answer"

We all know that mod will not decide only based on what users feel, they will also consider own conscience. So effectively "the moderator" also found it offensive.

In comments, I clarified that the Khajuraho sculptures belong to the **temple**, which is recognized by Indian government. It's neither offensive nor illegal to talk, view or cite them.

I would like to know under what category of guidelines of this site, these images are "offensive"?

I also request other moderators to come forward & provide their view on this topic. Because, I find them to be less enthusiastic on deletion. :-)

---

<sub>For those who consider Khajuraho as "dirty", may refer to [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VcThFnztv4w&feature=youtu.be) (41:00) video from a movie. The actor in that clip is late Vijay Anand, former head of censor board. Incidentally he wanted to liberalize the Indian film industry.</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me start off by saying I *too* found your answer a little offensive because the images you used unfortunately seem to be the highlight of your answer i.e., they are literally jumping out of the screen :P So it was difficult for me to read thru your answer fully without getting too distracted.

But I did not flag it because irrespective of how I feel, I should not flag a valid answer simply because *I* find it offensive. So I agree with you on that, i.e., *People have complained about these images being offensive* - is not reason enough to delete an answer.

However, I would suggest you to make it a little offensive by reducing the size of the images used. You can do it by editing the image link by adding a 'm' to the end.

E.g., If original image looks like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUZe.jpg):

[image]

Append an 'm' to the same image name makes it look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUZem.jpg):

[image]

Append an 's' to the same image name makes it look like this (https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFUZes.jpg):

[image]

You may also add a spoiler markup to the images, so that they will be visible only when the mouse hovers/clicks on it. This way, the supposedly distracting images will remain invisible for those who don't want to see it.
**[What's the exact syntax for spoiler markup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/72877/163449)**

Then probably flag it to undelete and see what happens.

Now, I find [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/704/2995) answer also a bit offensive. Wonder what the mods will do if a couple of users flag that answer as 'offensive'. I suspect the flags will be declined.

---

**Other issues**:

Other day, I flagged the comments under [this answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/7189/2995) as too many (35 comments). I asked them to be moved into a chat under the answer - which is the norm. It was declined by one of the mods without a follow-up comment. Clearly, a very biased action from the mod involved and using power to the mod's advantage.

> should probably move all comments to a chat – sv. Oct 6 at 20:45   **declined**

Here's [an answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/14459/2995) where another user explained why the answer was down-voted. The mod was supposed to update, correct the answer with the right sources instead of pointing to another question as the source - yet those follow-up comments are now deleted. The mod's original comment can be still seen but not the other user's responses. Again a clear sign of abuse of moderator privileges.

**Such absolutely unmoderator like behavior needs to STOP!!!**

Comment: Or a spoiler markup?

Comment: Yes, that might work too if OP wants it. No user (including the mods, as is clearly evident) wants to be forced to conform to site rules. But as OP clearly stated, I suggest you and the other mods write separate answers and explain when an answer is deleted and when it is not. Just a few users not liking an answer or a comment and flagging it is enough to delete it?

Comment: @sv. The 35 comments are very informative about "various events in chronological order". So, though i agree with your answer in general, i feel leaving those comments as such is beneficial to users as they some may not go and read chat rooms.

Comment: Probably you should have written "distracted" at "little offensive". The latter is a strong word. +1 for reducing image size. I wanted to do, but didn't know the way. That still may not help as the mod doesn't want the image. In any case, our focus has to be on the image as such. **Whether is it illegal/offensive to cite ancient sculptures, which are recognized by govt?"** May be you can add some lines on that. Regarding flagging, yes they are declined based on bias. See [this comment](http://tinyurl.com/zkdwyjk), where user accepts of using "hard words". But it's tiny part of bigger  issue.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, your answer on masturbation is actually good. That's the reason, I linked it as a source in my (deleted) answer. Just for the records I flagged it, so when it's declined I can update that in my question. Don't take this flag as any kind of retaliation from me. IMO your answer should have been accepted & you should have not written clarification edits in any apologetic way succumbing to public opinions. *VAtsyayana* was indeed a Vedic philosopher. His works are part of Hindu texts only.

Comment: @TheDestroyer I think useful information should be in the *answer* not in comments. Nobody is stopping the user from editing the answer and add additional information like the follow-up question and its answer. Mid-way thru those comments you already find one chat. So only a mod can decide, depending on the mood, when to move comments to a chat when not to? Rules should be same everyone. More than 10 comments under any question or answer is a 'noise' according to me.

Comment: @iammilind without considering moderators issue, you interpret differently when compared to  some users. So, it's just a Philosophical difference and i deleted my comment which was rude. So, don't take it personal. Also, everyone here should consider other views (which are in accordance with Scriptures), else we can't run this site (not pointing to you but for all). Have a look at this Question [What do the sculptures on hindu temples represent?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/3428/3500)

Comment: @sv. Yeah. Agree.

Comment: @iammilind Answers show other perspective (which is different to your view) about Kajuraho statues. My point is to show that perspective to you..

Comment: @iammilind both case are different my answer use kamasutra text and it's not as provocative as those images. But I do think that answer didn't required to be deleted but needed to add spoiler markup only. Anyways ur answer is also undeleted.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, *"my answer use kamasutra text and it's not as provocative as those images"*, with due respect, isn't it an opinion? For many, detailed description of masturbating technique is quite provocative. It literally teaches to those, who don't know. In a way, my & your answers are practically followed in chronological order by many people(sic). IMO, none is provocative, it's all based on viewers. For centuries, we are trained to act in certain way. People who are comfortable with such restricted way, make a great deal out of it & morally enforce others to do. Anyways, thanks for reply!