# How does this site deal with statements which are repeatedly made without references?

Tags: discussion, support

If a user makes repeated claims in his questions or answers which are not backed by any references (or which are yet to be proved) then what are the ways to deal with it?

This will only help a person to promote.some sectarian propaganda on this platform.

For example,

Some of the members try to include and promote a specific sect as most popular sect.

This statements are included in several or most of their questions and answers.

For example [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/) and [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/10162/7853)

Now what is the solution when senior mods themselves engage in such kind of propaganda?

Comment: Any examples of such posts?

Comment: Questions may not require references. If a question is trying to prove something instead of asking (i.e. not a real Qn), then good to vote for close or flag. No action should be taken against the user whatsoever, unless it breaks "be nice" policy.

Comment: You can explicitly mention the statements now. That will be helpful. Otherwise people may not be getting any clues.

Answer (score 6):

As said in [above comment](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/903/how-does-this-site-deal-with-statements-which-are-repeatedly-made-without-refere#comment3337_903), questions may not require references. But answers should have proper sources. An answer should cite references or sources (need not be an external site always) for majority of points or for "essence of the answer". For example, we don't need to cite a source for statement "Rama is son of Dasharatha" in an answer, unless if question asks "Who is father of Rama?".

if an answer has points which are not **very trivial** and if OP makes them repeatedly in his posts with no sources, flag the answer for moderator attention. We will add post notice to it and may even delete after specific amount of time **only if all points in answer have no sources**, as described in [this policy](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/3500). Trivial may be subjective in most cases, but we need to cite sources for all main points or for essence of the answer. For example, if a question is about "valor of Karna" and if OP says "Karna won many wars", then he/she should cite some references or sources for those wars.

Before flagging, you may do any one these actions if you find an answer repeatedly says the same thing with no sources.

1. Ask OP required sources or references for those statements in comments.
2. If you are not sure of flagging, inform any Mod in chat rooms.

**Note**: Don't flag answers or questions when you think any interpretation is wrong. For example, if you find a sentence which cites a *proper* reference and according to you intepretation is wrong, don't flag those posts. But flag those posts, if source cited is not related to the post.