# Please try to appreciate others' views, answers and perspectives - even if you don't agree!

Tags: discussion, voting, up-votes

In continuation of [this](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/659/2995) post...

...we are not always right. So when you see someone writing an answer that contradicts your own views, beliefs, thinking etc., let's try to upvote their answers if they make some compelling arguments with proper references (such as [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/8995/2995) one).

Quoting a relevant [story](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/apple-story-changes-your-perception-amardeep-kumar) I've come across recently:

> What a wonderful story!
>
> It changes perception on perception ... do read
>
> A teacher teaching Maths to a six-year-old asked him, “If I give you
>   one apple and one apple & one apple, how many apples will you have?”
>
> With a few seconds the boy replied confidently, “Four!”
>
> The dismayed teacher was expecting an effortless correct answer
>   (three).
>
> She was disappointed. “May be the child did not listen properly,” she
>   thought.
>
> She repeated, "please listen carefully."
>
> It is very simple. You will be able to do it right if you listen
>   carefully.
>
> If I give you one apple and one apple and one apple, how many apples
>   will you have?”
>
> The boy had seen the disappointment on his teacher’s face.
>
> He calculated again on his fingers.
>
> But within him he was also searching for the answer that will make his
>   teacher happy.
>
> This time hesitatingly he replied, “Four...”
>
> The disappointment stayed on teacher’s face.
>
> She remembered that the boy loves strawberries.
>
> She thought maybe he doesn’t like apples and that is making him lose
>   focus.
>
> This time with exaggerated excitement & twinkling eyes she asked ...
>
> “If I give you one strawberry & one strawberry & one strawberry, then
>   how many will you have?”
>
> Seeing the teacher happy, the young boy calculated on his fingers
>   again.
>
> There was no pressure on him, but a little on the teacher.
>
> She wanted her new approach to succeed.
>
> With a hesitating smile, the young boy replied, “Three?”
>
> The teacher now had a victorious smile. Her approach had succeeded.
>
> She wanted to congratulate herself.
>
> But one last thing remained.
>
> Once again she asked him, “Now if I give you one apple and one apple
>   and one more apple how many will you have?”
>
> Promptly the answer was “Four!”
>
> The teacher was aghast.
>
> “How.... tell me, How?” she demanded in a little stern and irritated
>   voice.
>
> In a voice that was low and hesitating young boy replied, “Because I
>   already have one apple in my bag.”
>
> **Lessons to Learn**: When someone gives you an answer that is different
>   from what you are expecting, it is not necessarily they are wrong.
>
> There may be an angle that we may not have understood at all.
>
> **We need to learn to appreciate and understand different perspectives.**
>
> **Quite often, we try and impose our perspectives on others and then
>   wonder what went wrong.**
>
> The next time someone gives you a different perspective than yours,
>   sit down and gently ask "can you please help me understand"?

Comment: This post is helpful, but less likely to get answer as this is answer in itself. May be you can think of posting this as an answer to this question: [Why are we so sure about everything while commenting or answering?](http://meta.hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/496/1049)

Comment: Yes, rather than trying to impose our own belief in answers/questions.. we should try to answer/question from all perspectives..