# (UPDATE: NEW ANSWER RIGHT BELOW) Where have the votes gone? A reflection into the dismal state of the site

Tags: discussion, community, voting, site-evaluation

An observation of the site over a one year span has revealed a dismal state of voting or shall we say that voting has become virtually non-existent. *We have two of our moderators active and flags being handled speedily also now.*

The current statistics (as on 13/02/2021 IST 8:14 PM) as per [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/53689/hinduism) show about **641 avid users** and 9,665 out of 16,783 logins per day, and despite such overwhelming numbers, even well researched questions and answers fail to get a commensurate response. Well framed, undisputed, on-topic posts which pique the interest of the community in general too, manage to merely *clamber up* to 3 to 4 votes or in an extremely rare scenario 6 to 8. This is in complete contrast to the scenario prevailing until recently, about a year and a quarter back (please correct me if I’m wrong)

As per our site’s help centre, let’s see [why voting is important](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote):

> Voting is central to our model of providing quality questions and answers; it is how... 
>  * ...good content rises to the top
>  * ...incorrect content falls to the bottom
>
> Moderator elections are an important part of that plan, **but voting on questions and answers is the primary mechanism through which the community governs the site** on a day to day basis
>
> not to mention that upvotes are a great way to thank the author of a good post for the time and effort put into writing it!

And encourage people to post better answers, when the community appreciates them.

As per the above help centre guidelines, voting will be a great solution to the [problems plaguing the site](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/please-share-your-problems-and-suggestions-to-improve-the-site?r=SearchResults) as well as the phasal sluggishness. (Would’ve answered this question but the problem of lack of votes is grave enough to require a separate post). Yes there will always be a difference of opinion, but that shouldn’t deter us from voting on another truly good post by the same person. It is our duty to give due appreciation. No one’s efforts must go futile.

---

**One of the Possible Reasons for the Site not Graduating**
As per the [policy](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/10/21/when-will-my-site-graduate/) of the entire Stack Exchange network, sites in beta require relatively lesser reputation as compared to graduated sites for similar privileges. Here is a comparison of a few of the important ones:

| **Privilege** | [Hinduism SE](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) | [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| **Highest Privilege** | **5,000** | **25,000** |
| **Trusted user - expand deletion privileges** | **4,000** | **20,000** |
| Cast close and reopen votes | 500 | 3,000 |
| Access moderator tools (deletion) | 2,000 | 10,000 |
| Edit Qs and As | 1000 | 2000 |
| Create tags | 150 | 1500 |

It can be seen that, privileges on a graduated site are nearly five times than a beta site. The [statistics of our site](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/567/quarter/hinduism/2021-01-01/20129#20129) currently reveal that there are only 5 users out of a total of 16,783 users that have a reputation of 25000+. They have gotten their reputation due to the earlier non-reluctancy with appreciating by voting. In the event of graduation, most of the burden will rest on these 5 and very few others slowly climbing there, as opposed to a substantial number who are greater than 5000 (or at least 4000) and currently have all privileges.

The only way users’ can possess reputation enough to unlock privileges on a graduated site is by the *community as a whole contributing votes* (not unnecessary ones though)

---

**Arbitrary and Conservative Arithmetics:** 
Let’s take 640 (not even 9655) avid users as our base and adopting a conservative and arbitrary method

1. Of these let’s assume a figure as high as 90% don’t analyse each and every question on the feed and may innocently tend to skip through them. That leaves us with 64 viewers.
2. Of 64 viewers, say half are people to whom even questions that are interesting/ appealing (not very narrow) are not appealable. That leaves us with 32 users liking a post.
3. Say half of them (320) are new and are not aware of the rules 32/2 = 16 old users liking a post
4. Even assume half of these 16 tend to read and like, but genuinely forget to vote or don’t have that ingrained in them. That leaves us with 8.

Even as per the above extremely conservative calculation, a well researched post, generally appealable to half the old people, which maybe skipped by 90% of the avid users, and some with mentality not to vote, it is expected to garner at least 6-8 votes (which as I cited above is an extremely rare phenomenon nowadays for posts which would’ve ordinarily gotten 15-20 votes). **In my opinion they should at least get 12-15 votes, in line with the earlier vote count.**

---

**A list of 10 good general posts (IMO):**

1. [Do the eight immortals (Including Lord Hanuman) still exist in Kaliyuga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44733/20129), but a [similar post](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/22693/20129) 3 years earlier by the same user managed to get 6 votes.
2. [What is the difference between Bhakti Yoga and Karma Yoga?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44699/what-is-the-difference-between-bhakti-yoga-and-karma-yoga) - a lot may know the answer, but someone did make an effort to ask it and respond to it.
3. [Which parts of Virāṭ Purūṣa are constituted by Varṇa Saṃkara-s & Mlechcha-s?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44697/which-parts-of-vir%C4%81%E1%B9%AD-pur%C5%AB%E1%B9%A3a-are-constituted-by-var%E1%B9%87a-sa%E1%B9%83kara-s-mlechcha-s)
4. [Why was traveling to Kalinga (modern-day Odisha) considered a sin?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43254/20129) - well researched answer from scriptures.
5. [Can we do Mantra japa while consuming non vegetarian on a daily basis?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44324/20129) - very relevant answer in modern day scenario.
6. [Fasting for health in Hindu scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44493/fasting-for-health-in-hindu-scriptures)
7. [Do sinners directly get moksha if they die in Varanasi?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44158/do-sinners-directly-get-moksha-if-they-die-in-varanasi)
8. [What happens if a person without Upanayana gets married?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43797/20129)
9. [What is the benefit of writing ramakoti book or sivakoti book?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43925/20129)- under-appreciated answer.
10. [What are six darsanas or philosophies, known to be limbs of Shiva?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/43430/20129)

     Some may obviously not agree with the above list but I hope it gets the message across.
    *Disclaimer:* these do not intend to advertise any particular users, but are appreciable in general. I have purposely not included my own posts :P

---

Please everyone may feel they vote enough but very evidently that’s not the case.

Questions:

1. Can we please increase the voting on the site?
2. What measures can we take to improve the voting on the site and thereby breathe life into it?
3. Any other suggestions?

I sincerely hope we come up with a solution and act on in instead of a standard discussion going in vain.

Answer (score 7):

I appreciate this well written post. And I always urge everyone to vote often, and vote responsibly.

Some motivation for voting-

Just by voting, users can get silver and gold badges.

- **Civic Duty** for voting 300 times.
- **Sportsmanship** for voting on 100 answers on questions where your answer has positive score.
- **Electorate** for voting on 600 questions. (Must be at least 25% of all votes)

Comment: Related: https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/668/277

Answer (score 7):

We can initiate sort of award kind of activity in chatroom.

> **Post of the day**

This post can be a question or an answer.
We can discuss on criteria of choosing post of the day.  For example a well researched Question or an answer can be called post of the day. And whoever is online in chat, can participate in voting that up.

Comment: So what we can do for this: have a meta only. Choose a post of the day or maybe a week or month, based on criteria we’ll discuss later. That should be posted on one meta thread. And from that we pick it and put it in chat too. That way it’ll be formalised because many people don’t access the chatroom too. Something like what Pandya used to do with old posts. Only here no one will lose rep but instead get everyone to upvote

Comment: How we will filter out a well researched post which wasn't received well by the community; is what we would need to work on.

Comment: Also, how about - That you can leave part of it on the individual post ka author. For eg. If you feel your chardham answer didn’t receive good votes, you can probably post it in the under appreciated section of the thread.

Comment: Go to the tools option abs check, near review queues it shows max votes max viewed etc.

Comment: That word "ka" though... @Archit

Comment: @Archit Idea is posts should be well received by community which are being ignored. So may be we can put one particular check i.e. in small time frame which posts got many views. This is one of the filter for questions rather than answers.

Comment: Cool sounds nice. What also think of something for those actually good posts which are overlooked. Can we do something of those two. Ya ya but this suggestion of highest viewed and low votes is important. The only issue is if people didn’t like it. Meaning they viewed it but didn’t like it eg. saurav Dey’s Question on Lakshmiji

Answer (score 5):

I suggest we should post a similar meta post every end of the month, with a collection of curated good questions and answers. I remember Pandya trying something similar before. This might work as people are more active in meta than in chatroom (or main :P ).

We can name something catchy like "Monthly curated good posts" and link the previous post for users to check all such posts. Eventually, we will create a good timeline for users to go through the posts.

Since you have started this, better if you volunteer the same every month. From my end, I can't volunteer as I am an enthusiast but not an expert to know the good/not so good posts.

Comment: "I am an enthusiast but not an expert to know the good/not so good posts." -- isn't there anyway to drive it from numbers like #of visits on the Q etc.. if we do opinion based good Qs every month then it will invite troubles in long run.

Comment: I don't think we should limit it in any way. If someone disagrees with the curated list, they can add their own in an answer or edit the question itself. But definitely not removing any posts. Maybe we should discuss this more once all agree or check how other SEs are doing.

Comment: Besides your good suggestion, how about an under-appreciated post day. Every Sunday or so, take the weeks posts and whoever feels that their post (having net 0 or positive score, not negative) has been under-appreciated, they can too add theirs in the under appreciated post section?

Comment: That I feel will create noise on meta. Having one post for every month is enough. We are curating the list of good questions. If anyone wants attention to their post irrespective of underappreciated or other concerns, they can always add the answer to that post. The main intention of this post will be so users can actively vote on posts (upvote or downvote - mostly upvote as this will be good posts).

Comment: Wait you didn’t understand what I said. See for example we create one meta question - this will talk about post of the day/ list of good curated posts. Cool? Then in the answers, every week or every month so eg. January week 1. Xyz are the posts of the week or month. And xyz are the under appreciated posts. Can’t explain here . Will need to demonstrate so that everyone can understand. It’s like the timeline you said

Comment: @YDS, can we figure something from the [tools section here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tools)?

Comment: +1 for this statement: "This might work as people are more active in meta than in chatroom (or main :P )."